# How to stream the logs in docker python API?

Tags: python, docker

I am building an image from a Dockerfile using the docker python API.

```
import os
import sys
import os.path
import docker


client = docker.from_env()
try:
    here = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    no_cache = False
    dockerfile = os.path.join(here, 'app', 'nextdir')
    image = client.images.build(path=dockerfile, tag='app:v.2.4', nocache=no_cache, stream=True)
```

The operation finishes successfully, however I was not able to stream the logs. The API says:

> Return a blocking generator you can iterate over to retrieve build
>   output as it happens

when stream=True.

How can I get these logs in python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Streaming the docker build logs can be done using the low-level APIs given in [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) as follows,

```
        here = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        dockerfile = os.path.join(here, 'app', 'nextdir')
        docker_client = docker.APIClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
        generator = docker_client.build(path=dockerfile, tag='app:v.2.4', rm=True)
        while True:
            try:
                output = generator.__next__
                output = output.strip('\r\n')
                json_output = json.loads(output)
                if 'stream' in json_output:
                    click.echo(json_output['stream'].strip('\n'))
            except StopIteration:
                click.echo("Docker image build complete.")
                break
            except ValueError:
                click.echo("Error parsing output from docker image build: %s" % output)
```

Comment: I am getting the below error, 

`AttributeError: 'method-wrapper' object has no attribute 'strip'` . Is there any recent developments ?

Comment: @AmanDalmia I was running into the same issue, and after debugging, I created [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70059037/9027587). Newer versions of the python docker sdk decode the json output automatically so calling `__next__` returns a string. Also, it must be called as a function, like `generator.__next__()`

Comment: Parsing the json output is not required, you just have to pass in the argument ```decode=True``` into the ```docker_client.build```, which returns a ```dict``` object on each ```generator.__next__()``` This can save time parsing (and reduce potential parsing errors)

Answer (score 8):

According to the [docs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.build), the image build now returns a tuple with both the image and the build logs

> The first item is the Image object for the
> image that was build. The second item is a generator of the build logs as JSON-decoded objects.

And modifying @havock solution accordingly:

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
image, build_logs = client.images.build(**your_build_kwargs)

for chunk in build_logs:
    if 'stream' in chunk:
        for line in chunk['stream'].splitlines():
            log.debug(line)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this works. In the high-level API (client.images.build) you might get two values back, but the call is blocking. Whereas if you run the low-level API (client.api.build) it worked (at least for me) but with a single return value.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the [low-level](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-docker.api.build) API client. The `build()` function will return a generator that you can iterate to grab chunks of the build log.

The generator will yield a string containing a JSON object, you may call `json.loads()` on it or you can use the `decode=True` parameter in the `build()` function that will do that for you.

Once you grab the `'stream'` key from the yielded dictionary you may just `print()` it, but if you need to send it to a logger it may be better to do it line by line, as the chunk received will contain more than one line.

One option of such code is as follows:

```
from docker import APIClient

client = APIClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')

# Build docker image
log.info('Building docker image ...')
streamer = client.build(
    decode=True,
    path=args.path,
    tag=args.tag,
)

for chunk in streamer:
    if 'stream' in chunk:
        for line in chunk['stream'].splitlines():
            log.debug(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Docker low level build has the ability to directly decode the output to a dictionary. For that use `decode=True`.

I used mashumaro to convert the dictionary to a dataclass. This is useful if you like type hints. To use dataclasses you need at least python3.7.

Install mashumaro:

```
pip install mashumaro
```

The dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class DockerStreamOutput(DataClassDictMixin):
    stream: str = None
    aux: str = None
```

Build your image:

```
from mashumaro import DataClassDictMixin, MissingField
generator = client.api.build(
            path=container_path,
            tag=tag_name,
            dockerfile=dockerfile_path,
            decode=True  # encode to dict
        )

for line in generator:
    try:
        stream_output: DockerStreamOutput = DockerStreamOutput.from_dict(line)
        stream: str = stream_output.stream
        if stream:
            logging.info(stream.strip())
    except MissingField:
        logging.error(line)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you had trouble with the answers above, I was able to get what I needed using this:

```py
def _build(self, **kwargs) -> bool:
    """**kwargs should contain the same values expected by the docker.from_env().api.build() method"""
    print("building...")
    try:
        response = [line for line in docker.from_env().api.build(decode=True, **kwargs)]
        if not response:
            print("Error! Failed to get a response from docker client")
            return False
        for result in response:
            for (key, value) in result.items():
                if isinstance(value, str):
                    print(value)
        return True
    except (docker_error.BuildError, docker_error.APIError) as error:
        print("Error! {}")
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of the python docker sdk, you can still use the high-level api functions, as they return tuples of the form `[object_created, generator]` when needed.

This has been tested in `python 3.10`, running `docker==4.2.2` and `click==8.0.3`

Here is the function I am using to log docker output from a cli I am building, based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540254/how-to-stream-the-logs-in-docker-python-api/43903346#43903346):

```
def log_docker_output(generator, task_name: str = 'docker command execution') -> None:
    """
    Log output to console from a generator returned from docker client
    :param Any generator: The generator to log the output of
    :param str task_name: A name to give the task, i.e. 'Build database image', used for logging
    """
    while True:
        try:
            output = generator.__next__()
            if 'stream' in output:
                output_str = output['stream'].strip('\r\n').strip('\n')
                click.echo(output_str)
        except StopIteration:
            click.echo(f'{task_name} complete.')
            break
        except ValueError:
            click.echo(f'Error parsing output from {task_name}: {output}')
```

Example usage:

```
import docker
from docker.client import DockerClient

docker_client: DockerClient = docker.from_env()

image_obj, log_generator = docker_client.images.build(path='path/to/my_api_dockerfile')
log_docker_output(log_generator, "Building Django API image")
```

Comment: It seems that the docker_client.images.build is blocking. I would like to see the logs being printed out as I build the image. How would that be possible you think?

Comment: @d56 You can use @Paul's function with the lower level API too which will print as it builds.  Example usage:  `log_docker_output(docker.APIClient().build(path='path/to/my_api_dockerfile', decode=True), "Building Django API image")`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this solution worked for me:
`environment={"PYTHONUNBUFFERED": "1"}`

Answer (score -2):

The [docs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html) state...

> If you want to get the raw output of the build, use the build() method in the low-level API.

Have you tried that?